# Ciclos con do while y TRY CATCH en java

Tags: java, bucles, while

Estoy intentando hacer un código en java que permita hacer operaciones básicas con 2 números introducidos a través del teclado y estoy trabajando con `TRY` y `CATCH` para evitar llenar la pantalla de rojo con los errores. Al finalizar las operaciones una simple pregunta "Desea continuar?".. Y aquí es donde tengo las dudas y problemas. Si presiono 1 continuo, si presiono cualquier otro numero se cierra y si presiono una letra, el programa muestra el texto "indique un numero" pero termina, y lo que desearía es que volviera a preguntar si DESEO CONTINUAR... Como puedo hacer ese ciclo? Desearía cerrar con el numero 0 y que si introduzco una tecla me diga que no es un numero y repita la pregunta de "desea continuar?"

De igual forma, si al inicio coloco una letra en lugar de numero, indica que coloque un numero y pasa por todas las condiciones y termina el programa..

Aquí el código.. Muchas gracias por su paciencia..

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException; import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operaciones { public static void main(String[] args) {

    int terminar = 0;

    Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Introduce un numero  ");
            int a = sr.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Introduce un numero  ");
            int b = sr.nextInt();

            int suma = a + b;
            System.out.println("La suma es: " + suma);

            int multiplicacion = a * b;
            System.out.println("La multiplicacion es: " + multiplicacion);

            int resta = a - b;
            System.out.println("La resta es: " + resta);

            try {
                int division = a / b;
                System.out.println("La division es: " + division);
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.out.println("No se puede dividir entre cero.");
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("El valor no es un numero");

        }

       try  {
           System.out.println("Desea continuar? presionar 1");
           terminar = sr.nextInt();

       }catch (InputMismatchException e){
           System.out.println("Indique un numero");
           }
       
         }while (terminar == 1) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomendaria hacer uso de la excepciones por partes a modo de practica,primero realizas una captura de excepcion del primer numero solicitado,luego del segundo, esto para no repetir todo el proceso si solo ingresas una letra como numero. Finalmente en las opciones de repetir el proceso

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operaciones { public static void main(String[] args) {

    int terminar = 0;
    boolean pass;//hacer uso de un booleano
    int a=0,b=0;//declarar variables globales

    Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
    
do{ 
    do{
    try{    
    System.out.println("Introduce el primer numero");
    a =sr.nextInt();
    pass=false;//asignar false para no entrar al bucle
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
      System.err.println("El valor debe ser un numero entero");
      pass=true;//asignar true para entrar al bucle 
      sr.nextLine();//limpiar el buffer
    }
    }while(pass);


    do{

    try{    
    System.out.println("Introduce el segundo numero");
    b =sr.nextInt();
    pass=false;
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
      System.err.println("El valor debe ser un numero entero");
      pass=true;;
      sr.nextLine();
    }
    }while(pass);


    int suma = a + b;
    System.out.println("La suma es: " + suma);

    int multiplicacion = a * b;
    System.out.println("La multiplicacion es: " + multiplicacion);

    int resta = a - b;
    System.out.println("La resta es: " + resta);

    try {
    int division = a / b;
    System.out.println("La division es: " + division);
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    System.err.println("No se puede dividir entre cero.");
    }

    do{
    try{
    System.out.println("Desea continuar? : 1");
    System.out.println("Desea Finalizar? : 0");
    terminar=sr.nextInt();
    pass=false;
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
     System.err.println("No es un numero");
     pass=true;
     sr.nextLine(); 
    }}
    //si pass es true o se ingresa un valor diferete a 1 y 0 se repetira el bucle
    while(pass||terminar!=1&&terminar!=0);
   //si ingresas 0 se termina el programa
    if(terminar==0){System.exit(0);}
  // si se ingresa 1 se repetira todo el programa
}while(terminar==1);


    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! No habia usado el boolean porque aún no lo manejo bien. Creo que el problema estaba en el uso de los Try y Catch. Gracias por el consejo para su uso. A seguir practicando.

Answer (score 2):

Excelente la respuesta de Dramaturgo, acá les dejo una versión sin bucles, que se vale de la recursión, para obtener el mismo resultado.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operaciones {
   
   Scanner sr = new Scanner( System.in );
   
   void ejercicio() {
      int primerNumero = recibeNumero( "Introduce el primer numero" );
      int segundoNumero = recibeNumero( "Introduce el segundo numero" );
      
      int suma = primerNumero + segundoNumero;
      System.out.println( "La suma es: " + suma );
      
      int multiplicacion = primerNumero * segundoNumero;
      System.out.println( "La multiplicacion es: " + multiplicacion );
      
      int resta = primerNumero - segundoNumero;
      System.out.println( "La resta es: " + resta );  
      
      try {
         int division = primerNumero / segundoNumero;
         System.out.println( "La division es: " + division );
      }
      catch( ArithmeticException e ) {
         System.err.println( "No se puede dividir entre cero." );
      }  
      finaliza();             
   }
   
   void finaliza() {
      int terminar = recibeNumero( "Si desea continuar, ingrese \"1\", sino, ingrese \"0\"" );
      if( terminar == 0 ) {
         return;
      }
      else if( terminar == 1 ) {
         ejercicio();
      }
      else {
         finaliza();
      }      
   }
   
   int recibeNumero( String msg ) {
      System.out.println( msg );
      try {
         return sr.nextInt();
      }
      catch( InputMismatchException e ) {
         System.err.println( "El valor debe ser un numero entero" );
         sr.nextLine();  //limpiar el buffer
         recibeNumero( msg );
      }
      return 0;
   } 
   
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Operaciones ope = new Operaciones();
      ope.ejercicio();
   }
}
```